# Whether all shards explain stages are same?

Tags: mongodb

I have tree shard servers and one mongos server. I connect to the mongos server to run some queries. When I look at the explain output from these queries, it always gives me the same number of explain stages for each shard server. I wonder whether I can get a different number of explain execution stages for differen shard server. I have tried to create an index on one shard but not the other two. But it still gives me a same number of stages on explain query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have "SINGLE_SHARD" as a stage
e.g.

```
{

 "queryPlanner" : { 

    "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1, 

    "winningPlan" : { 

       "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
```

It means that a single shard was sent to the query (as opposed to when you don't specify a shard key and it has to be sent to multiple shards)